# Unable to restore nuget packages as other user

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

When I run `dotnet restore` as my default user, everything works fine:

```
> dotnet restore
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /home/gitlab-runner/builds/LaP8vSUZ/0/my-group/my-api/src/my-api.Api/my-api.Api.csproj (in 441 ms).
```

But when I try to run it as other user, it fails:

```
> runuser gitlab-runner -c 'dotnet restore'
/home/gitlab-runner/builds/LaP8vSUZ/0/my-group/my-api/src/my-api.Api/my-api.Api.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find package MyCompany.Platform.Aspnet with version (>= 1.4.4)
... Found 26 version(s) in MyCompanyFeed [ Nearest version: 1.4.4-beta ]
```

It seems that `dotnet restore` under `gitlab-runner` does not see the newest package version. Tried to clean cache with:

```
runuser gitlab-runner -c 'dotnet nuget locals all -l'
```

Not helpinh.

As the result, my CI/CD fails as it is unable to build project. Why it happens and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Clearing global packages and temp helped:

```
> runuser gitlab-runner -c 'dotnet nuget locals global-packages -c'
...
> runuser gitlab-runner -c 'dotnet nuget locals temp -c'
...
> runuser gitlab-runner -c 'dotnet restore'
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /home/gitlab-runner/builds/LaP8vSUZ/0/my-group/my-api/src/my-api.Api/my-api.Api.csproj (in 441 ms).
```

Wondering why `all` parameter didn't cleared global :(